# Overriding models.save() in Django ORM to use a stored procedure?

Tags: django, postgresql, partitioning

I'm putting together a partitioned table in postgres which will be used by an API written in Django.  Postgres has a number of issues with this, most of them having to do with the RETURNING clause in SQL returning NULL or creating duplicate records (google postgres partition returning if you want to learn more).

I believe the solution is to override the save() method in ORM to use a stored procedure or custom SQL, but how do I map the incoming arguments to a custom SQL statement?

Ideally it would look like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) but instead of calling the super method it would map the args to a custom SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is make trigger before insert/update on PostgreSQL site.

Comment: I'm using a [standard partitioning strategy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) in postgres already.  The issue is that the trigger function can either return NULL or NEW.  When it returns NULL, the RETURNING clause will return NULL as well.  If you set it to return NEW the RETURNING clause will work, but the data will be inserted into the child _and_ parent tables!